# I need to add up the values in a column in a tidyverse dataframe between row indices

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tidyverse dataframe and I want to add up the values in a column between a contiguous subset of the rows. I want to identify the column by its name, not column number.

e.g. for column "volts" add up all the values between rows 100 and 199. ( then, using a loop I will add up between 200 and 299,...etc)

I'm struggling to find anything helpful in SO and Google so any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: That's why I provided you links to get that baseline knowledge. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

if your column is called `volts` inside a dataframe called `df`:

```
step = 99
intervals = seq(1,nrow(df),steps)

sumVector = lapply(intervals,function(x){
              df$volts[x:(x-step)] %>% sum
            })%>% unlist
```

I also assumed that you only need a single column summed this way, if you want several, you could do it with nested `lapply` calls.

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr and group_by:

```
library(dplyr)

data(storms)
df <- storms

df <- df %>% mutate(id=floor(1:n()/100)) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(volts_sum=sum(wind)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-id)
```

Replace wind by the column name of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers no doubt have lots of advantages but at this early stage in my journey into R I prefer a more intuitive approach. I managed to get this working and it's easier for me to follow (and it would be easy to update r1 & r2 in a loop):

```
  jt = tibble( x=c(5,6,7,8,9), y=c(9,8,7,6,2))
  r1 = 2
  r2 = 4
  mycolname = 'y'       # parameterise the column name too
      
  subset_col_mean = colMeans( jt[r1:r2, mycolname])   #includes BOTH row's values


  print(subset_col_mean)
```

Or, the `map*()` set of functions offer a cleaner but still very clear option:

```
map_dbl( jt[r1:r2, mycolname], mean)  # can use median, max, min, sum,.. instead of mean
```